# How do I prove that my formula to generate any diagonal sequence or any column sequence is true, in Pascals Triangle?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I have a generalized formula that I believe will generate any diagonal sequence and any column sequence for Pascals Triangle, but I do not know how to prove that it will do what I believe it will do?

[image]

Given:

$$F(N,K) = \frac{(N+K-2)!}{(N-1)!(K-1)!} : [N\ge1, K\ge1]$$

Any $N_{th}$ (or $K_{th}$) diagonal sequence can be generated by substituting the $N_{th}$ diagonal into $K$ and then iterate $N$. For example, to generate the sequence for the $6_{th}$ diagonal, set $K=6$ in $F(N,K) = F(N,6)$ and then iterate $N$ to create that diagonal sequence.

$$6_{th-sequence} = F(N) = \frac{(N+4)!}{(N-1)!(5)!} $$

For column sequences, the center column is labeled column zero. With that said, to generate any column sequence, for example the sequence for column $3$, set $N = K+3$ into $F(N,K) = F(K+3,K)$ then iterate $K$.

$$3_{rd-sequence} = F(K) = \frac{(2K+1)!}{(K+2)!(K-1)!}$$

I claim that

$$F(N,K) = \frac{(N+K-2)!}{(N-1)!(K-1)!}$$

can generate the sequence of any diagonal or any column by substituting into $N$ or $K$ the appropriate value to set the formula for that sequence. Is there a way to prove $F(N,K)$ to be true or valid?

Comment: It is much nicer to number your diagonals starting at $0$ instead of $1$. Then you simply get $F(N,K)=\frac{(N+K)!}{N!K!}$. This is the number of paths starting from the top of the triangle, taking $K$ steps in the down-left direction and $N$ steps in the down-right direction, arranged in any order, which necessarily ends at the intersection of the $K$th and $N$th diagonals.

Comment: To add to this comment, notice that for a change of variables $n = N-K$ and $k=K$ you get $F(n,k) = \begin{pmatrix} N \\ K \end{pmatrix}$, which is known to generate Pascal's triangle.

Comment: @ChrisMzz. I'm not interested in generating Pascals Triangle, am interested in isolating any sequence in the triangle and generating it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Isn't your definition of $F(N,K)$ valid by construction ? I'm not sure what you're asking, seeing as you're clearly aware of the role of binomial coefficients in the triangle.

Comment: You could check your formula agains known formulas. For example, the central column vlaues are given by $v=(2n)!/(n!)^2$. There are other formula for other columns. For diagonal number $3$, it's just the triangular numbers given  by $n(n+1)/2$. If you do that for few columns and diagonals, you will get an idea if your formulas are correct.

Comment: @user25406 yes I did check it against known sequences way back when I did this. I'm basically looking for confirmation. So far it looks good from the responses I've read. Thank you.